# Need to create a proc or anonymous block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

We have one table as following:

```
Table name: metadata_table
```

Structure is as follows:

```
S.No    Tablename             Column

 1     Fct_sales_summary      wk_units
 2     Fct_exp_summary        mn_units
```

`wk_units` in the table `Fct_sales_summary` are **columns** and are in range `wk_units1` to `wk_units105`. Similarly in `Fct_exp_summary`.

We need to create **proc or anonymous block** which will pick the columns name from tables and give us the result as that of select query.

For example, the proc should give us a result of following query:

```
select wk_units1,wk_units2....wk_units105 from cmn_sls_dm.Fct_sales_summary;
```

After that similarly for:

```
select mn_units1,mn_units2....mn_units105 from cmn_sls_dm.Fct_exp_summary;
```

Comment: -anybody plz let me  know any idea on this

Comment: @Irveen - I think if you read some of the comments to your other related questions on this you'll understand why interest is fading - please give some indication that you're reading the other answers.

Comment: @Irveen, what you are asking for is completely doable (if I understand the request), however, as dpbradley points out, people are unlikely to help given that you do not seem to be interested in behaving as appropriate for this site.